# Ubuntu Java OpenJDK not finding shared libraries

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu, jdbc, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to get the oracle oci driver working in ubuntu.

I have openjdk version "1.8.0_91"

I have installed sqlplus and I can see it's shared libraries in a folder here:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
```

At first sqlplus didn't work and was complaining it could not find shared libraries.

To fix this I have created a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf` called `oracle.conf`

It contained as single line:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
```

I then ran `sudo ldconfig` and `sqlplus` now works.

My problem is that Java programs still can't find the library. I run the command:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties
```

and I can see the property for the libraries:

```
java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/jni
    /lib
    /usr/lib
```

When I run the Java code I get the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path
```

When I run ldconfig -v I can see a section at the top:

```
 - /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib:
               liboramysql12.so -> liboramysql12.so
               libmql1.so -> libmql1.so
               libnnz12.so -> libnnz12.so
               libons.so -> libons.so
               libipc1.so -> libipc1.so
               libocijdbc12.so -> libocijdbc12.so
               libsqlplusic.so -> libsqlplusic.so
               libsqlplus.so -> libsqlplus.so
               libheteroxa12.so -> libheteroxa12.so
               libclntsh.so.12.1 -> libclntsh.so.12.1
               libociei.so -> libociei.so
               libclntshcore.so.12.1 -> libclntshcore.so.12.1
               libocci.so.12.1 -> libocci.so.12.1
```

and as you can see the library is present.

I thought that maybe the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH may need to be set. It is currently empty. If I set it:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
```

I get the same error when running my code and `java -XshowSettings:properties` hasn't changed.

Does anyone know why java is not picking up the library?

Comment: Why don't you add `/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib` to java.library.path? Do I get it right that `libocijdbc12.so` is there?

Comment: Hi, yes it is there. I think I have found my mistake when I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH I didn't export it. Although I was hoping I wouldn't need to set it if I had ldconfig using it. (my ldconfig must work because sqlplus works)